# how to do two search in the same page with meta_search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I have two list in a page, one for a model_1 and another for a model_2. When I click the sort_link of a column meta_search send the param "search[meta_sort]=column_name.asc". The problem is in the controller because the two models get filtered with the same search parameters:

```
#in the controller
@search_for_model_1 = Model1.search(params[:search])
@model_1s = @search_for_model_1.all

@search_for_model_2 = Model2.search(params[:search])
@model_2s = @search_for_model_2.all

#in the view
<%= sort_link @search_for_model_1, :name %>
<%= sort_link @search_for_model_2, :name %>
```

the sort_links are in different html tables, one showing model_1 fields and the another showing model_2 fields, when I click in any column name link, the param I get in the controller is params[:search], I have no way to know if the column link was clicked from model_1 or model_2 html table.

I want change the param name "search" for something like "search_for_model_name" then in the controller:

```
#in the controller
@search_for_model_1 = Model1.search(params[:search_for_model_1])
@model_1s = @search_for_model_1.all

@search_for_model_2 = Model2.search(params[:search_for_model_2])
@model_2s = @search_for_model_2.all
```

I could not find the way to change the param name using the helper method sort_link that meta_search provide. Or is there a different manner to do this?

Comment: what does the sort_link in your view look like?

Comment: could you post the code for the sort_link helper method? Also, is the controller code you're showing in the `index` method or a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_link` uses the `:as` option just like `form_for`

```
<%= form_for @search, :as => :q do |f| %>

<%= sort_link @search, :field, :as => :q

@search = Model.metasearch(params[:q])
```

So do that with different names for each model.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you just do something like this

```
:search_for_model_2 => :search_field
```

but I can't say for sure without seeing your view.

Comment: I have changed the original post because it had a copy paste mistake and I put how sort_links are in the view

Answer (score 0):

graywh's answer is not working for sort_link, this is the correct solution:

```
#in the controller
@search_for_model_1 = Model1.search(params[:model_1], :search_key => :model_1)

@search_for_model_2 = Model2.search(params[:model_2], :search_key => :model_2)
```